# MySQL JOIN syntax, can't see reason for error

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to find why this query is failing

```
SELECT
fID, Date, host_id, t1.tname AS opposition, HA, opp_id, t2.club_id AS clubid, c.club, c.venue
FROM(
SELECT
id fID,
hteam_id host_id,
date Date,
CASE WHEN (hteam_id='13') THEN 'H' ELSE 'NULL' END HA,
ateam_id opp_id
FROM fixtures WHERE hteam_id='13'
UNION ALL
SELECT
id,
hteam_id,
date,
CASE WHEN (ateam_id='13') THEN 'A' ELSE 'NULL' END,
hteam_id
FROM fixtures WHERE ateam_id='13'
) as tot
JOIN teams t1 ON tot.opp_id=t1.id
JOIN teams t2 ON tot.host_id=t2.id
JOIN clubs c ON tot.clubid=c.id
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Everything was fine until I added the third JOIN on table clubs.

Error #1054 - Unknown column 'tot.clubid' in 'on clause'

Comment: As it says there is no `clubid` in your `tot` query. You have only `SELECT
fID, host_id, Date,HA, opp_id`

Comment: "I am struggling to find why this query is failing".  Maybe learn to format your code properly.  It's too long to comment, so I put it on answer section.  You can read your code there and see that there's no `clubid` on your table `tot`.

Comment: you should get upvotes points your SQL formatting only @Eric, the topicstarters SQL code is hard to read i had even trouble figuring the SQL out..

Answer (score 1):

If you format your code properly, you'll see more easily.  There's no column `clubid` on your table `tot`.

```
SELECT fID
    , Date
    , host_id
    , t1.tname AS opposition
    , HA, opp_id
    , t2.club_id AS clubid
    , c.club, c.venue
FROM(
    SELECT
        id fID,
        hteam_id host_id,
        date Date,
        CASE WHEN (hteam_id='13') THEN 'H' ELSE 'NULL' END HA,
        ateam_id opp_id
    FROM fixtures 
    WHERE hteam_id='13'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        id,
        hteam_id,
        date,
        CASE WHEN (ateam_id='13') THEN 'A' ELSE 'NULL' END,
        hteam_id
    FROM fixtures 
    WHERE ateam_id='13'
) as tot
JOIN teams t1 ON tot.opp_id=t1.id
JOIN teams t2 ON tot.host_id=t2.id
JOIN clubs c ON tot.clubid=c.id
ORDER BY Date ASC
```